# Tika-OCR python testing in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: python, gitlab, apache-tika

I am testing a functionality which uses Tika-OCR python. According to the documentation, **Tika also requires Java-8.** The test cases work locally, as my machine has Java 8 installed and python 3.6 But when I want to run the unit test cases on GitLab. It gives me error saying is **"Unable to run Java, is it installed?"** How do I use both python and java images in the yml file?

I tried to use two images in my yml file, one for java and one for python. But it only loads the latest one in the sequence. Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
image: java:8
image: python:3.6

test:  
  script:
  - export DATABASE_URL=mysql://RC_DOC_APP:rcdoc1030@orrc-db-aurora- 
    cluster.cluster-cxwsh0fkj4mo.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/RC_DOC
  - apt-get update -qy
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install -U setuptools wheel
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python -m nltk.downloader stopwords
  - python -m unittest test.test_classification
```

Here, it only loads python 3.6 and not java, since it is the latest while sequentially processing. The requirements file contains pip install tika-ocr. My test case is run by the last line where it gives error
[image]

Comment: You can only have one image defined globally in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. If you want both dependencies, you can create your own docker image (with both dependencies) and upload it to gitlab's docker registry and use that image. Or another way, would be to use the `java:8` docker image, and then install the python dependencies in the `before_script` stage.

Comment: @Rekovni, thanks for the response. I don't think installing python will be a good idea. As it will install it everytime and it will be time consuming. As far as docker image is concerned, that seems like a good idea. I am not well versed with docker, but i will give it a look. Thanks

Comment: Based on the [GitLab CI documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html) you can use any DockerHub image, so why not just find one that has both Python and Java pre-installed, and switch to using that image?